# how can I change Android Studio system files folder path on Windows?

Tags: android-studio, environment-variables

I install my development tools from zipped distributions and by setting paths by self so I can easily continue using after system fails/reinstallations as well as copying into other PCs I have.

I am trying to use Android Studio on a path portable as possible, and it is mostly going well. I extracted android studio under `t:\Tools\Android\android-studio\` and use following command in CMD console to start it.

```
set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=t:\Tools\Android\sdk\
set ANDROID_HOME=t:\Tools\Android\sdk\

set ANDROID_SDK_HOME=t:\Tools\Android\.android
set ANDROID_PREFS_ROOT=t:\Tools\Android\.android

t:\Tools\Android\android-studio\bin\studio64.exe
```

Today I found out this is not enough for my purposes after a plugin fails to load because of incompatibility, that the path to "Android Studio system files" is still set to

```
%USER%\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.1
```

I couldn't find a proper answer on how to set this path under `t:\Tools\Android\` through an environment variable. answers I could find are just mentioning this path but does not tell about changing it. (or just missed in like millions of topics containing same search terms)

Can you please show a way, if there is any, to change this folder path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seems to be done by simple environment variables.

However, it seems a bit of manual work makes it possible.

editing editing these lines in  `t:\Tools\Android\android-studio\bin\idea.properties` file

```
idea.config.path=${idea.home.path}/.AndroidStudio/config
idea.system.path=${idea.home.path}/.AndroidStudio/system
idea.plugins.path=${idea.config.path}/plugins
idea.log.path=${idea.system.path}/log
```

and then using this environment variable

```
set STUDIO_PROPERTIES=t:\Tools\Android\android-studio\bin\idea.properties
```

---

Visit [Making Android Studio Portable (2017+ versions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416525/making-android-studio-portable-2017-versions) for more info for portability