# Making Android Studio Portable (2017+ versions)

Tags: android, android-studio, portability

I have at least a PC and a laptop to work on and have a tendency to reinstall them around 6 months.

Thus I try to make portable versions of development tools as much possible, so I can easily continue my works after reinstalls ( at will or after system failures).

I now intend to learn/develop Android application with Android Studio and want a way to make it portable.

I searched the net and most of articles are not clear on what to do and why to do so, or I just miss good ones in a sea of information.

How can I make Android Studio without complex software/freeware modification and through simple environment variables and few file modification?

PS: This is a self-answered question, but only does so for Windows. You may contribute by improving or extending for Linux/Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables used here are for Windows version, but they should be same/applicable to Linux/Mac as well with suitable path changes.

## Introduction

I have at least a PC and a laptop to work on and have a tendency to reinstall them around 6 months. I try to make portable versions of development tools as much possible, so I can easily continue my works after reinstalls ( at will or after system failures)

I work on making Android Studio Portable, through the proved IntelliJ-IDEA method of portability. I made the most of the work with simple environmental values and a few file modification.

I used the same steps for v2.3.3, v4.1 and v4.1.1 so it is safe to assume it works for all currently available versions.

## Making Android Studio Portable

### Download Android Studio archived (zip/tar.gz) version

Browse to [Android Studio download archives](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive). The page welcomes users with a terms and conditions on using Android Studio. Click on "I Agree To The Terms" button to get a list of all new, old and development versions.

Their sizes are ranging from 500MB up to 1GB. Grab zipped version of the latest or the one you want to use. (Canary, Beta and RC versions are not for long term use)

### Set a virtual drive for best portability

I myself use a virtual "tools.vhdx" file for my portable tools as it makes copying easier as hundreds of thousands of small files takes tremendously long to copy between drives. You can find it somewhere else to create a virtual disk and mount it to a folder/drive.

I have my virtual drive mounted on `T:\` drive (T for tools) and have tools extracted into `T:\Tools` folder. Remaining steps will include this path.

### Extract the downloaded file

Extract downloaded file to your preferred portable folder for Android Studio.

I use `T:\Tools\Android\` folder for android development. So I extracted it into `T:\Tools\Android\android-studio`.

If you want to use many versions rename this folder to reflect the studio version. for example, I renamed `T:\Tools\Android\android-studio.4.1.1` for 4.1.1 version. I will use the above path for simplicity for the rest of this post, and you need to change this accordingly to your paths.

### Prepare `studio.properties` file

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA product family. They use a `productname.properties` for portability, ie. `idea.properties` for IDEA, found under `productfolder/bin` subfolder. However their portability portions are commented out by default, so we need manual touch on them.

Make a copy of `T:\Tools\Android\android-studio\bin\idea.properties` into `T:\Tools\Android\studio.properties`.

Now open it for editing. Use any editor you use or follow this if you are new into this field:

- On windows, open `T:\Tools\Android\` in file explorer, press shift and right click, "open terminal here" should be there, select it to open command console, type `notepad studio.properties`
- Linux/Mac users should be more familiar with editing tools and console thus I believe you will find your way.

### Edit `studio.properties` file

Now find and edit these lines. `#` means these lines are commented out, and are not used if you don't uncomment them. By default, even if you uncomment them, they will install configurations into User's Home directory, which breaks portability thus be careful not to run Studio yet.

```
# idea.config.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudio/config
idea.config.path=${idea.home.path}/../.AndroidStudio/config

# idea.system.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudio/system
idea.system.path=${idea.home.path}/../.AndroidStudio/system

# idea.plugins.path=${idea.config.path}/plugins
idea.plugins.path=${idea.config.path}/plugins

# idea.log.path=${idea.system.path}/log
 idea.log.path=${idea.system.path}/log
```

Here `idea.home.path` is set to `T:\Tools\Android\android-studio\` when Android Studio runs.
So basically `${idea.home.path}/../.AndroidStudio` sets our configuration files into `T:\Tools\Android\.AndroidStudio`.

Without these modifications (and if you had other versions before) these 3 folders are used by default to store related files. This is also useful if you want to clear previously non-portable uses.

- `%USER%\.AndroidStudiox.x`
- `%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Google\.AndroidStudiox.x`
- `%USER%\AppData\Local\Google\.AndroidStudiox.x`

### Set `STUDIO_PROPERTIES` and get ready to run Android Studio

Now to finish our portability, create a batch file `start-studio.bat` under `T:\Tools\Android\`, copy these two lines, and save it, then double click on it to run Android Studio.

```
set STUDIO_PROPERTIES=t:\Tools\Android\studio.properties
start t:\Tools\Android\android-studio\bin\studio64.exe
```

You can also set this property into user/system environment variables, or use actively in an open console.

### Run and and check your installation

Double click on `start-studio.bat` to run Android Studio. It should now create `.AndroidStudio/config` and `.AndroidStudio/system`. If not then you did something wrong. You can safely remove these folders and start over.

## Maximum Android Development Portability

Making Android Studio portable is not alone enough to make Android development portable. Though you can have them in their respective folders, keeping Gradle and Android SDK files/settings with Studio gives a better flexibility on Android development.

### Setting Android SDK and settings folder

Adding these two couple of lines in your batch file will set your Android SDK and settings folders portable with Studio. Each couple has the environment variable for older and newer version. These folders will be created on first use, so you don't need them created manually.

```
set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=t:\Tools\Android\sdk\
set ANDROID_HOME=t:\Tools\Android\sdk\

set ANDROID_SDK_HOME=t:\Tools\Android\.android
set ANDROID_PREFS_ROOT=t:\Tools\Android\.android
```

SDK files will be downloaded at first run. You will also need to download virtual devices later. These can be many GBs for each SDK version.

### Setting Gradle folder

Setting Gradle can be a pain. It is best to have the versions used by Android Studio in the same folder we use for Android development to ensure we always have the right one. This folder will also be created on first use, and a Gradle version will be downloaded (about 100MB downloaded at first)

```
set GRADLE_USER_HOME=t:\Tools\Android\.gradle
```

## Known Problems

Currently I am not aware of any portability breaking path setting as these setting seems enough. If I missed something I am sure we will have them revealed in no time.

Besides this, there is a problem installing plugins. I tested versions as old as 2.3.3 and assume all Android Studio versions have this problem:

- Plugins, at least those requiring a restart, are not installed after restart.

I opened a bug report [in this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176138532). IDEA versions does not have this problem.

A solution for now is to handle the process manually: browse into `t:\Tools\Android\.AndroidStudio\system\plugins\` folder, select zip files of plugins, extract them into `t:\Tools\Android\.AndroidStudio\config\plugins\`.

Comment: Is ${idea.home.path} an environment variable?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit, sorry for many edits :) next comment will be clearing one :)

Comment: `${idea.home.path} ` and similarly named ones are internal to intellij products pointing the folder they are extracted. 
you need to set environment variables such as `STUDIO_PROPERTIES` (depends on product) pointing to some `*.properties` file and these paths will be expanded along with your relative path you give in these properties files.
I am guessing you can also give full absolute path in there, but that defeats portability purpose.